# I want a function locked for a certain amount of time, what's the safest way to achieve this?

Tags: solidity, timestamp, timers

I want a store where someone can become `tokenOwner` for a certain amount of time. The following solutions seems the easiest:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract PromotedDapp is Ownable{

    uint price;
    address tokenOwner;
    uint nextOwnerAllowed;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function becomeOwner() public {
        require(now >= nextOwner);
        nextOwnerAllowed = now + 604800; // In a week
        tokenOwner = msg.sender;
    }

}
```

I know another option is to work with blockHeight since one block gets minted +/- every 10 seconds, what would be a reason to chose blockHeight over time in seconds?

Comment: Correction: a block is _mined_ about every 10 _seconds_.

Comment: You are completely right, edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Time is an interesting thing on the blockchain. The two choices are to use time (or timestamp) and the block height.

Block number is *generally* not advised, as the average block time is 15s. Because it is average, this means that blocks could be shorter (1s) or longer (1 min+). Depending on your application, this variance could mess up your calculations. Additionally, while the block times are ~15s now, that may change in the future because of the ice age or potential future upgrades that reduce this number.  Again, it is almost never a good idea to use block number.

Timestamps are generally advised in code like this. Timestamps on Ethereum are sent by the *miners* in each block they mine. There are rules surrounding this to avoid any malicious actions: miners cannot send a timestamp that is less than the one in the previous block and they cannot send one that is greater than 15s in the future. Because of these bounds, using a timestamp in solidity is a much better choice.

Comment: It sounds like for my app timestamps are for sure the best way to go, a 15 second margin would not matter. Thanks a lot shane :)